# Exercise on an operator defined in $L^2(0, 1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $T$ be an operator on $L^2(0, 1)$ defined as $T[f(x)]=f(\frac{x}{2})$. Find $\|T\|$ and $T^*$. Does $TT^*=T^*T$ hold? Find also eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$.

My attempt for finding $\|T\|$ is the following.
$$
\|Tf\|^2=\int_0^1|f(\frac{x}{2})|^2dx=2\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}|f(y)|^2dy\leq 2\|f\|^2\Rightarrow\frac{\|Tf\|}{\|f\|}\leq\sqrt2
$$
How can I prove the equality? Moreover, some hints for the other questions?

Comment: Let $f=\chi_{[01/2]}$, the characteristic function of $[0,1/2]$. What is $\frac{\|T(f)\|}{\|f\|}$? For finding $T^*$ look at$$(f,Tg)=\int_0^1 \overline{f(x)}g(x/2)\,dx = 2\int_0^{1/2} f(2x)g(x)\,dx\overset!=(T^*f,g)$$ Can you see what $T^*$ must be?